# How to populate FormView from SQLDataReader object?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sqldatareader, formview

I am new to ASP.NET and C#.  I am trying to display some basic information about a "supplier" which is retrieved from a database with a simple query.  I started off using a GridView, and it worked perfectly fine, but I like the look of FormView more.  The problem is nothing is displaying in the FormView... it is invisible.

Here is the C# code:

```
connection = new SqlConnection(connectionInfo);
connection.Open();

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select... from... where...");
SqlDataReader supplierReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

supplierForm.DataSource = supplierReader;
supplierForm.DataBind();

supplierReader.Close();
connection.Close();
```

And here is the ASP code:

```
<asp:FormView ID="supplierForm" runat="server">
    </asp:FormView>
```

This is for a class project, so I am not asking you to solve the problem for me. If somebody could just point me in the right direction, that would be great :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your binding seems correct.

Nevertheless you are missing the binding/markup to display the data in your page - how to do that
You might wanna check out these links: [MSDN Tutorial for Formview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb288035.aspx) and [FormView Control: Step by Step](http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-Tutorials/FormView-Control.aspx) .

Greetz